# Achieving smooth scrolling in a BlackBerry app

Tags: blackberry, scroll

I have developed a contacts screen in Blackberry. I have almost 40/50 
contacts each being displayed in a HorizontalFieldManager on screen. All the HFM are on one parent VFM.

In one short I am able to see 5 records. My problem is when I scroll down to the 6th, 7th record the screen is not showing the record on which my focus is present. Then after reaching the 10th record I can see the records from 6th to 10th position.

I want a smooth scrolling, just like the one in Blackberry Messenger.

Comment: This needed a [mcve] (MCVE) when it was posted and it has not attracted any useful answers, so it can be closed as Unclear or Lacking an MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListField , you can implement ListFieldCallback interface and custom draw each row using drawListRow method.

Comment: Hi York.No i dont want to use ListField.Bcos its device dependent.It works fine on 9800 but not on 9700 so i have developed a customized interface using VFM and HFM.........any suggesstion on this?